# Why does my variable change length in this example?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, base64, php-openssl

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a value. My example sometimes work but most of the time I am getting:

> openssl_decrypt(): IV passed is 20 bytes long which is longer than the
>   16 expected by selected cipher, truncating

These are my 2 methods:

**Encrypt**

```
public function encrypt(string $value)
{
    $iv = random_bytes(16);

    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($value, $this->cipher, $this->key, 0, $iv);

    return base64_encode($encrypted . '/' . $iv);
}
```

**Decrypt**

```
public function decrypt(string $payload)
{
    $payload = base64_decode($payload);

    list($payload, $iv) = explode('/', $payload);

    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($payload, $this->cipher, $this->key, 0, $iv);

    return $decrypted;
}
```

The length of my `$iv` variable has changed after I decrypt it. Could anybody tell me why this happens? Whenever I var dump the random bytes output I sometimes get weird characters as well that can not be rendered.

Could anybody point my in the right direction so I can fix this?

Cheers.

Comment: `/` is a Base64 character *if* you are *not* using the URL Safe alphabet; and it is a cipher text character. You should probably avoid using it as a delimiter. Also see RFC 4648.

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick. I will look into it a bit more. Maybe create an answer so I can accept it as the proper answer?

Comment: You shouldn't use a character delimiter in the first place. Since the IV has a fixed length, you should just *prepend* it and that way you'll always know how to extract it - just getting the first N bytes as a substring.